# Register a relatively large content in metadata

Tags: registration, spring-boot-admin

I use spring boot admin to manage various services

Register a relatively large content in metadata, because relatively large content may consume more network bandwidth, so I want to register it only when the client starts for the first time. The registration request is every 10 seconds, and the server cannot respond to subsequent registration requests. overwrite this content

Is there a better solution?

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why not fix the server to support multiple registration requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the interval with the property `spring.boot.admin.client.period` (in ms, default is 10000). See http://docs.spring-boot-admin.com/current/client.html

In general it is useful to have a periodic task, as also the server could be restarted and then reregistration is required.